# Question: What is the meaning of $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves

Question: What is the meaning of $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve?

Suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then I understand what $E(\mathbb{Q})$ means, it is those points $(x,y)$ on $E$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

1. I have read that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. But I don't know how to imagine / grasp the idea of $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.
2. My understanding is that it is the points $(x,y)$ on $E$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}_p$. Is that correct? How would one find such a point anyway, for example find such a point when $E$ has the equation $y^2 = x^3 - x$?
3. Is there any relation between $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and $E$ when viewed as an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}?$ I know that to study a curve $E$ sometimes we want to work over a finite field and using some techniques, one can find a point on $E$ modulo $p$ and then lift it up to $E$.
4. Lastly, it is a theorem that $E(\mathbb{Q}) / n E(\mathbb{Q})$ is finite. Is it also true when $\mathbb{Q}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just some comments. First, yes $E(\mathbb Q_p)$ is literally just "take the equation for $E$ and look at solutions where $x, y \in \mathbb Q_p$". Second "lifting points" is most easily done from $\mathbb F_p$ to $\mathbb Q_p$ via Hensel's lemma. Third, assuming good reduction and whatnot, if the coefficients for $E$ lie in $\mathbb Z_p$ or possibly in $\mathbb Z_p \cap \mathbb Q = \{ a/b : b \notin p\mathbb Z\}$, then your elliptic curve is a scheme over ${\rm Spec}(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Comment: Since $\mathbb Z_p$ has two prime ideals: $0$ and $(p)$, you get two fibers. One corresponding to $E(\mathbb Q_p)$ (over the $0$ ideal) and the other corresponding to $E(\mathbb F_p)$ (over $p\mathbb Z_p$). This scheme-with-two-fibres picture is often useful.

Comment: I actually have no idea what is a scheme (neither do I know what are bundles and all those stuff XD)

Comment: The scheme stuff means looking at the ring $\Bbb{Z}_p[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x)$, in particular at its prime ideals, localizations and residue fields. Some prime ideals contain $p$, the other don't contain any non-zero $p$-adic integer. For $E(\Bbb{Q}_p)/n E(\Bbb{Q}_p)$ you might want to look at $G=\Bbb{Q}_p^\times / q^\Bbb{Z}$ which is the $p$-adic analog of the multiplicative analog of complex tori, it is an elliptic curve and $G/G^n$ is finite because $\Bbb{Q}_p^\times/(\Bbb{Q}_p^\times)^n$ is finite.